# RuntimeError: `loss` passed to Optimizer.compute_gradients should be a function when eager execution is enabled. Working with Tensorflow 1.15

Tags: python, optimization, deep-learning, training-data, tensorflow1.15

I am trying to train a model using tensorflow 1.15 with eager execution enabled.
For train loss I am using

```
train loss = mse_loss*args.lmbda + bits_per_pixel_loss
```

I've defined the optimizer as below

```
main_optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimiser(learning_rate=1e-3)
```

Upto here the code is working fine
The error is coming in the minimizer part of the optimisation

```
main_step = main_optimiser.minimise(train_loss, global_step=step)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: `loss` passed to Optimizer.compute_gradients should be a function when eager execution is enabled.
```

So when I calculate train_loss inside a function say, `loss_computer`, built inside the train function and then using

```
main_step =main_optimiser.minimise(loss_computer, global_step=step)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'.
```

How can I train the model with eager execution enabled?
Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!